Why does Raspberry Pi Pico W make AP with default configuration?
import socket
import network

ssid = 'PICOlo amore'
password = '12345678'

led = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)

ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
ap.active(False)
ap.active(True)
ap.config(essid=ssid, password=password)

while ap.active == False:
  pass

print('Access point active')
print(ap.ifconfig())

I wrote this simple code to test Access Point on my Raspberry Pi Pico W, but it only works when I run the script manually. I uploaded this as main.py on pico and it does create an Access Point but instead of "PICOlo amore" I get "PICO3D53" as SSID and the password doesn't work. But as soon as I run the code myself, it works fine. Please help me fix this before I break this board 

Hmm, is there a boot.py file, or any other Python files on your Pico?

I added a flashing LED indicator to your code so that I could see if it was working, and it worked from Thonny, but it also worked standalone as main.py on the Pico without any issues.
But following the comment from @David, it might be best to clear your Pico of all files and folders apart from main.py. It might also be worth putting a small pause between ap.active(False) and ap.active(True).
Here is the modified code (including the addition of the code to blink the internal LED).
import network
from machine import Pin
import time

ssid = 'PICOlo amore'
password = '12345678'

led = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)  # Using the onboard LED

ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
ap.active(False)
time.sleep(0.1)
ap.active(True)
ap.config(essid=ssid, password=password)

while ap.active == False:
  pass

print('Access point active')
print(ap.ifconfig())

# Blink LED to indicate successful setup
for i in range(3):
    led.on()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    led.off()
    time.sleep(0.5)

If this still doesn't fix it, I would try it with a different WiFi (maybe tether you phone), and if that fails I would reinstall your UF2 boot file.

Thank you. I will try your recommendations.
